# Java. TDD. Как проверить в assertThat() что объект имеет определенный тип (как instanceof)

Tags: java, test-driven-development

Надо в тесте проверить что определенный объект имеет определенный тип.

```
boolean res = (desc[2][7] instanceof Place);
assertThat(res,is(true));
```

Что-бы вот так не писать... Есть ли какой-то метод в util?

Comment: не уверен насчет assertInstanceOf, но assertTrue здесь бы здорово помог

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Нужно использовать org.hamcrest.CoreMatchers.instanceOf

Ответ:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/12404813/4828657

Comment: Спасибо! Вы очень помогли!

Answer (score 2):

*Пример:*

```
import org.junit.Test;

import static org.hamcrest.CoreMatchers.instanceOf;
import static org.junit.Assert.assertThat;

abstract class AbstractClass {
}

class ClassImp extends AbstractClass {
}

public class InstanceOfTest {

    @Test
    public void testInstanceOf() {
        final AbstractClass subClass = new ClassImp();
        assertThat(subClass, instanceOf(AbstractClass.class));
    }
}
```